# How to ensure an S3 bucket name is not used with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

I know the `data aws_s3_bucket` resource can be used to get a reference to an existing bucket, but how would it be used to ensure that a new potential bucket name is unique?

I'm thinking a loop using random numbers, but how can that be used to search for a bucket name which has not been used?

Comment: Hi, Sorry just to understand your case, when you create an S3 bucket, you can omit the name to get a random name or use the `bucket_prefix` attribute (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#bucket_prefix) to assing a unique name with a prefix (e.g mybucket-3218389) on the bucket creation. The main problem that I see with your approach is that in case you could extract a unique name, maybe is not available anymore when you actually want to use it.

Comment: My case is that I'd like to create a bucket with a specifically structured name (to meet our in-house and AWS resource naming standards) but be sure that the name is unique. If `bucket_prefix` can be used to basically define the whole name and simply add an extra random (but unused) number and therefore guarantee a unique bucket name, that's good enough. (Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution by using `bucket` instead of `bucket_prefix` and `random_uuid`, for example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_s3_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-s3-bucket-${random_uuid.uuid.result}"
}

resource "random_uuid" "uuid" {}
```

This will give you a name like this:

```
my-s3-bucket-ebb92011-3cd9-503f-0977-7371102405f5
```

Answer (score 14):

As discussed in the comments, this behaviour can be achieved with the `bucket_prefix` [functionality](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#bucket_prefix)

This code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_s3_bucket" {
  bucket_prefix = "my-stackoverflow-bucket-"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

Produces the following unique bucket:

[image: bucket image]